# Symmetry arguments and derivation for product of gamma matrices and derivatives

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation, dirac-matrices

I am trying to work with the Dirac equation and the solution for the Klein-Gordon equation for some derivation and I stomped on the following problem in my derivation.

$\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}\right\} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}$

I know that the equality holds, I found it in the lecture notes I am using and I know that in order to prove it I have to use symmetry and antisymmetry arguments regarding the gamma matrices and the derivatives and some Clifford algebra. What would be the steps in the derivation to show that?

Comment: Hint: the derivatives commute with each other.

Comment: how do you get the summation in my equation? could you write the steps down? @Triatticus

Comment: I know they do but I cannot show it myself with all the steps could you please write them down? I am not completely familiar with Clifford algebra and symmetry arguments @ConnorBehan

Comment: Just add the term $\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}$ to your original line and recognize this is twice the right hand side of the equation after using what Connor suggested. No need to invoke any deep identities with the gamma matrices to get the result.

Comment: Do you know  why the trace of the product of a symmetric with an antisymmetric tensor vanishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of the comments after some errors.
$$\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} \partial_{\mu}\right)=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\gamma^{\mu} \gamma^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu} \gamma^{\mu}\right) \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\gamma^{\mu}, \gamma^{\nu}\right\} \partial_{\mu} \partial_{v}$$